# Json return each function

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Getting a json response from an ajax function that returns the code below:

```
["Please enter a Name","Please enter a Email","Please enter a Date","Please enter a message"]
```

The problem is that my current code will only show the last message, instead of all of the messages.

Jquery code is:

```
    var result = jQuery.parseJSON(response);

            console.log(response);

            $.each(result, function(key, value){ 

                if(key == 'success') {
                    // console.log(response);
                    success.find(".message").text(value);
                    success.slideDown();
                    success.delay(4000).fadeOut();

                }
                else {
                    // console.log(response);
                    error.find(".message").text(value);
                    error.slideDown();
                }


            })
```

How can I show each error message separately?

Comment: please explain what you expect the code to do and show relevant html. There is no property shown in array that would match `'success'` so something isn't right in what you have shown

Comment: Success isn't been sent yet which will only be one message. errors has multiple hence it not been shown above.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is replacing text. Instead try using append 
`success.find(".message").append(value + '<br />');`

And same with error `error.find(".message").append(value + '<br />');`

Comment: Thanks - how do I insert a line break after each error?

Comment: Also If you click submit the same object gets added - which I think it will when using append.

Comment: what same object? Can you please explain more. Btw I updated my answer

Comment: I got the update - thanks, as the output is an error object, when submit is clicked the object appends to the existing html - rather than replacing it.

Comment: So essentially when first clicked I see 4 messages, when second click i see 8 messages

Comment: in that case above the `each` loop do `success.find(".message").empty()` and similarly for errors too

Answer (score 0):

I would consider changing how you structure the reponse.

See a js fiddle of the code here:  http://jsfiddle.net/xrmgeazs/  or  http://jsfiddle.net/xrmgeazs/1/ with success option

eg from php:

```
$response = json_encode( array(
 'success' => false,
 'errors' => array(
   'name =>"Please enter a Name",
   'email => "Please enter a Email"
  )
) );
```

echo $response;

The in your js eg:

```
var result = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
if( result.success ){
  //do your success code here
} else {
  //start by clearing previous errors
  $('form p.error').hide();

  //loop your errors here
  for (var key in result.errors){
     var errorName = key;
     var errorMessage = result.errors[key];

     //now place your error and show accordingly.
     $( 'div.'+key ).append('<p>'+errorMessage+'</p>');
  }


}
```

HTML EG:

```
<form action="something.php" method="post">
<!-- add rel fields as appropriate -->
<!-- also note this is a very simple structure and could be expanded for richer ui -->
<div class="name">
  <input type="text" name="name"/>
</div
<div class="email">
  <input type="text" name="name"/>
</div
</form>
```

Comment: Any benefit to using the above method over mine (performance etc)?

Comment: Also errors are being set dynamically. which means your process above would not work.

Comment: incorrect. i have added to the html structure to explain more. this method is for dynamic forms with ajax.  This allows the errors to be placed at the correct place.

Comment: this method, the client is agnostic the actual errors thus could be pulled from anywhere. The errors are placed into the form element parent container.

Comment: added jsfiddle example